# How to close connection for Node.js http.createClient?

Tags: node.js, http, connection

Is there something like

```
remote_client.close()
```

or

```
request.close()
```

for closing the http.createClient connection?

It seems like in some occasions, the socket connection is still hanging there after the "response" event is emitted and properly handled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of node.js (0.4.8).

The syntax for creating clients has changed. You now have

[`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/all.html#http.request)

Which returns a [`ClientRequest`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/all.html#http.ClientRequest) which you can [`.end`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/all.html#request.end) and it gives you a [`ClientResponse`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/all.html#http.ClientResponse) in the callback.

The `ClientReponse` is just a [`Readable Stream`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/all.html#readable_Stream) and you can [`.destroy`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/all.html#stream.destroy) a stream

Comment: Should I use http.createClient or just http.request?

Comment: @murvinlai I think createclient is deprecated. Use request

Comment: Thanks.  I ran into problems with createClient with load testing.. let me chagne the code to request now.  thankx100

Answer (score 4):

Except for certain rare and extraordinary circumstances, your connections are performing correctly and will close by themselves, (or more precisely, will be closed automatically by your computer operating system's TCP stack.)

The issue you are seeing is that the socket underlying the connection will only be closed once all of its data have been delivered and acknowledged, and after the TIME_WAIT period has expired. This is well defined and perfectly normal behavior.

For an explanation of why this is required, see

- [UNIX Socket FAQ» 2.7 - Please explain the TIME_WAIT state](http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=2941)
- [TCP Tutorial](http://www.ssfnet.org/Exchange/tcp/tcpTutorialNotes.html#ST)

But the bottom line is: don't worry about sockets; they're your operating system's responsibility.